# VueJS : reverse data array has no effect

Tags: vue.js

In this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/djsuperfive/svctngeb/ I want to reverse the `structure` array in `data` when I click the button.
Why are the rendered list and the dump of `structure` not reactive whereas the `console.log` reflect that the reverse was effective ?

The code :

HTML

```
<div id="app">

  <draggable v-model="structure">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in structure" :style="'background-color:'+item.color">
      {{ item.title }}
    </div>
  </draggable>

  <button type="button" @click="reverse()">Reverse structure</button>

  <hr>
  <strong>dump structure:</strong>
  <pre>
    {{ structure }}
  </pre>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      structure: [{
          title: 'Item A',
          color: '#ff0000'
        },
        {
          title: 'Item B',
          color: '#00ff00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Item C',
          color: '#0000ff'
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    reverse() {
      console.log(this.structure[0].title);
      _.reverse(this.structure);
      console.log(this.structure[0].title);
    }
  }
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max!
Try to replace line:

```js
_.reverse(this.structure);
```

with

```js
this.structure.reverse();
```

I guess, Underscore.js does not have `reverse` method, because JavaScript has native one.
Everything should work fine with native [JS Array reverse function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).
Good luck!

Comment: You're right Evgeny ! I also just found that it's working with the native reverse method.

Comment: Great to hear that!) Congratulations =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that Vue does not detect that your array has changed: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

The solution is to either replace `this.structure` with a new array or to have a reverse function that uses [Vue.set()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

```
this.structure = _.clone(_.reverse(this.structure));
```